# how to use python to parse ossec rules xml

Tags: python, xml

I have a ossec rules XML file, with content like this:

```
<var name="SENSITIVE_DIRECTORY">^/root|^/proc|^/etc|^/$</var>
<var name="BAD_WORDS_OPS">failure|error|bad |fatal|failed|illegal |denied|refused|unauthorized</var>

<group name="local,ops,syslog,sudo,pam,">

  <rule id="101000" level="4">
     <if_sid>5715</if_sid>
     <srcip>!10.83.60.54</srcip>
     <srcip>!10.83.60.55</srcip> 
     <description>Except IPs approved.</description>
   </rule>
</group>
```

I am trying to use python to parse this xml, but I get this error:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: junk after document element: line 10, column 0
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
  from xml.etree import ElementTree

  def read_xml(text):
      root = ElementTree.fromstring(text)
      lst_node = root.getiterator("person")
      print lst_node

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      read_xml(open("test.xml").read())
```

Comment: have you tried wrapping up your xml with a `<root>` tag? your existing sample isn't a valid one

Comment: BTW, the word is **"parse"** not "prase".

Comment: this file is ossec rule,so i have a lot of file,so can  not add <root> tag for everyone,so python can parse like this xml file?

Comment: @robert, please see my updated answer for your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrap your xml with a tag  like this

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def read_xml(text):
    root = ET.fromstring('<root>'+text+'</root>') # just wrap it with a root tag
    for el in root.iter('srcip'): # I changed the tag to srcip since your sample hasn't got "player"
        print el.text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    read_xml(open("yourfile.xml", "r").read())

!10.83.60.54
!10.83.60.55
```

Comment: this file is ossec rule,so i have a lot of file,so can  not add <root> tag for everyone,so python can parse like this xml file?

Comment: @robert, if you cannot add tag on file level, you can do this on parse level, I've updated the answer accordingly